# Looping through json array in python

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have JSON in an array that i am importing into my script

```
"ip_address": [
"192.168.0.1",
"192.168.0.2",
"192.168.0.3"
]
```

I am loading the JSON and declaring a variable titled ip_address.

```
data = yaml.load(message)
    for d in data: 
        ip_address = (d.get('ip_address'))
```

I am attempting to loop using python through the ip addresses.

```
for address in data['ip_address']:  
      print(address)
```

I am now getting an error that tells me

```
string indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: show how `ip_address` variable is created

Comment: Paste full code. This part is useless.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license). If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request)?

Answer (score 4):

The reason why it's printing individual numbers is because the address is a string. Hence, it's not really each number that's being printed, but rather each letter of a string. Consider:

```
word = "abc"
for letter in word:
    print(letter)

# prints:
# a
# b
# c
```

Therefore, it means somewhere you're assigning individual IP addresses to a variable, and then iterate through that variable (which is a string). Without you providing more code on how you get the `ip_address` variable, it's hard to say where the problem is.

One way to print your IP addresses (assuming you have them in a dict):

```
addresses = {"ip_address": [
    "192.168.0.1",
    "192.168.0.2",
    "192.168.0.3"
]}

for address in addresses["ip_address"]:  # this gets you a list of IPs
      print(address)
```

Even if you have them somewhere else, the key insight to take away is to not iterate over strings, as you'll get characters (unless that's what you want).

**Updated to address edits**

Since I do not have the file (is it a file?) you are loading, I will assume I have exact string you posted. This is how you print each individual address with the data you have provided. Note that your situation might be slightly different, because, well, I do not know the full code.

```
# the string inside load() emulates your message
data = yaml.load('"ip_address": ["192.168.0.1", "192.168.0.2", "192.168.0.3"]')
ip_addresses = data.get('ip_address')

for address in ip_addresses: 
    print(address)
```

Comment: Ran that, but I'm getting an error :list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: That was only an example - it will most likely not work in the code you have (as I do not know how it looks). You should edit your question to include more information. For starters, where `ip_address` in `for` loop is defined.

Comment: I have updated the answer. I'm still a little unclear what the `message` in `yaml.load(message)` looks like exactly, so it's a bit hard to guarantee this will work. However, the idea of what must be done should be clear. If it doesn't, please update the question specifying what `message` looks like (a small, working snippet is enough) and I will try to help.

Answer (score 2):

In your case `ip_address = '192.168.0.1'`

Are you sure you have the right value in `ip_address`?

Comment: Yes, this error only occurs when i put the for loop in. This is a loop problem, cant figure out why its looping through individual characters and not strings.

Comment: because you set `ip_address` to a string not to a list. you can print the type of the variable: `print(type(ip_address))`

Comment: `for ip in obj['ip_address']` will work fine where `obj` is the loaded json

Answer (score 1):

I tried following :

```
ip_address = [ "192.168.0.1", "192.168.0.2", "192.168.0.3" ]

>>> ip_address = [ "192.168.0.1", "192.168.0.2", "192.168.0.3" ]

>>> 

>>> for i in ip_address:  

...     print i
```

... 
It printed

```
192.168.0.1

192.168.0.2

192.168.0.3
```

and it seems to be working fine for me .

Comment: because you're iterating through a `list` and that wasn't the question